# How do I upgrade Group Policy for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

How do I upgrade Group Policy for Windows 7? Currently when I edit a policy I only see settings for 2000/XP. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a Windows 7 computer you can install [RSAT](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7D2F6AD7-656B-4313-A005-4E344E43997D) on then this will give you access to the new group policy options.

You also need to copy the ADMX templates to the proper SYSVOL folder.  See this [link](http://angrytechnician.wordpress.com/2009/11/05/the-angry-technicians-guide-to-managing-windows-7-you-idiots/) for help.

Comment: ???  RSAT is to administer Windows Server from a Windows client PC, it won't give you access to something that isn't already there.

Comment: RSAT contains the new templates, but you're right they need to be copied to the server. See my edit above.